# Mongoose not returning, but mongo shell is

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose on my node app, and I want to get a seller by its email:

```
getSellerByEmail : function(email,next){
        var Seller = mongoose.model('Seller');
        console.log(inspect(email));
        Seller.findOne({'email' : new RegExp(email, 'i')}, function(seller){

            next(seller);
        });
    }
```

When I try to login, mongoose does not return the new user. But when I try to create another user with the same email, the server executes this function correctly and it returns the new user.

Also tried with `{'email' : email}` and It returns `null`, but when I do this query on mongo shell, it returns correctly.

```
db.sellers.findOne({email : 'email@email.email'});
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54b94759b042bdbf19cb7b97"),
   "name" : "Nome da Empresa",
   "cnpj" : "123123123",
   "email" : "email@email.email",
   "password" : "$2a$08$6UvW8Bux3CwUMok8ac12Sehbd.xCHnVUI51ZwhtGKBjkSa6/MrqUu",
   "__v" : 0
}
```

I'm new to mongodb + mongoose, so I know it's a dumb question, but I just can't realize what is wrong... I've also created a `findSellerById()` function, and it works perfectly.

**EDIT 1:**

Using Mongoose debug, here's what it's printed:

```
Mongoose: sellers.findOne({ email: 'email@email.email' }) { fields: undefined }
Mongoose: sellers.findOne({}) { fields: undefined }
```

As you can see, also tried with no parameters, no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function passed into `findOne` takes two parameters (error and doc), so you're treating `seller` as the error parameter instead of the doc parameter.

So your function should look like this instead:

```
getSellerByEmail : function(email,next){
    var Seller = mongoose.model('Seller');
    console.log(inspect(email));
    Seller.findOne({'email' : new RegExp(email, 'i')}, function(err, seller){
        next(seller);
    });
}
```

Comment: It's working, thank you very much! But do you know why it worked before?

Comment: I can't say, but this is definitely the right way. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, maybe you could try this:

```
Seller.find({email: seller.email}, function(err, seller){
    console.log(seller);
});
```

This solved mine, hope it will solve yours too !

Comment: Already tried that, no success. I noticed another thing, this function is also called when a seller wants to sign up, so I call it to check if the email isn't already in the db, and it works! 
It returns correctly! Really, have no idea why on the login it doesn't. 
Both queries are exactly the same.. I checked them on `mongoose.set('debug', true);`

Comment: @KayanAlmeida What did you specifically try? The key point is that both the `find` and `findOne` callbacks take two parameters, not one.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I edited my answer with the mongoose debug output, but as I said before, this `findOne` is called before, to check the email uniqueness, and works fine. It's the same function, with the same input. Maybe a connection problem?